# Form size issue with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 7 x64, and some of my existing code no longer functions as expected. Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create a C# Winforms project (with framework 2.0)
- Size "Form1" to be 300x300
- Set the border style to "FixedSingle"
- Disable the min/max buttons
- Display a messagebox in Form_Load that displays "this.Bounds.ToString()"

If you run this in the debugger, it will display the correct size (300x300). If you run the EXE outside of VS2012 it will display the wrong size (290x290). This code works fine in Visual Studio 2010. How can the IDE make a difference if I'm still using the same framework libraries? Can anyone else repro this issue using the steps above, or have any thoughts on why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: It has something to do with this line in the designer file: 

this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);

Somehow this translates to 300x300. If you comment out that line and put in this.Width=300 and this.Height=300 everything works. There is some sort of scaling going. Perhaps someone else can tell us that the point of ClientSize is and what's going on?

Comment: VS2010 did the same thing, it converted the ClientSize to a usable form size including the border. My big issue is the inconsistency between running under a debugger and not. It should be the same either way, but unfortunately it's unusable the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely caused by a slightly different window style being set on the form,
[according to the reference source, this functions is called to transform the client coordinates](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,11678):

```
internal Size SizeFromClientSize(int width, int height) {
    NativeMethods.RECT rect = new NativeMethods.RECT(0, 0, width, height);
    CreateParams cp = CreateParams;
    SafeNativeMethods.AdjustWindowRectEx(ref rect, cp.Style, HasMenu, cp.ExStyle);
    return rect.Size;
}
```